# How to get ID value using map()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've page that contain the *list button* and *search button*.

**index.php :**

```
<li class="page-item" id="'.$i.','.$record_per_page.'"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);" >'.$i.'</a></li>    
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="insert your keyword ..." aria-label="Search" id="budget_keyword" name="<?=$record_per_page;?>">
```

**script.js :**

```
$(document).on('click','#table-content .page-item',function () {
    var mode = this.id.split(',');
    var page = mode[0];
    var p = mode[1];
    var keyword = $('#budget_keyword').map(function() {
                  return this.id.value;
                  });
    $.ajax({
        url: "paging.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { page: page, p: p, keyword: keyword },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#table-content').html(data);
        }
    })
});
```

My *Goals* are : 
When user click the *li button*, then it will pass 2 variables which containing values from `#page-item` and `#budget_keyword` id
I already got the value of #page-item from my script above, but for the #budget_keyword, it seems returning an object which i cannot understand below :

```
  Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object(1) }
```

I just need the value from user input text inside searchbox (#budget_keyword)
Can someone give me an idea ?
sorry for my bad english

Comment: seems like multiple inputs with same `id` exist in your HTML. and due to that `keyword` is not coming properly (or in other words `map()`) not working

Comment: @Anant Singh already check whole document and only one #budget_id exist, also for the label i'm using 'for' instead of 'id', so it must be selected properly

Comment: `this.id.value`, `this` is going to be your element and `id` is going to be the string value for the id of that element. It is not going to have a `value` property. If you are trying to get the id it should just be `this.id`. If you are trying to get the value of the input it would just be `this.value`

Comment: @owf  if only one `id="budget_keyword"` exist in whole document. then directly do :- `$("#budget_keyword").val();`

Comment: @Anant Singh this works great, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @Patrick Evans thanks for your suggestion, yes i've mistake, i don't need the 'id', just value instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like multiple inputs with same `id="budget_keyword"` exist in your HTML.Due to that `keyword` is not coming properly (or in other words to say `map()` not working).

You can use `.next()` to get desired keyword. Check below code:

```
$(document).on('click','#table-content .page-item',function () {
    var mode = this.id.split(',');
    var page = mode[0];
    var p = mode[1];
    var keyword = $(this).next('.form-control').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "paging.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { page: page, p: p, keyword: keyword },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#table-content').html(data);
        }
    })
});
```

Note:- if only one `id="budget_keyword"` exist in whole document,then directly do:

```
var keyword = $('#budget_keyword').val();
```